# Difference between using Pandas isin() and merge() to subset a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames df1 and df2 and both have a column named `ID`.  Can someone help me to understand the difference between subsetting by doing

```
new_df = df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'].unique())]
```

and subsetting by doing

```
import pandas


unique_id_df = pandas.DataFrame(df2['ID'].unique())
unique_id_df.columns = ['ID']
new_df = df1.merge(unique_id_df,
                   on='ID',
                   how='inner')
```

I am aware that there is some speed difference between the two methods and that the ordering of the rows are different.  But the returned `new_df`s are of the same shape.  Do the `new_df`s contain the same information?

Comment: Yes, they are logically equivalent, as the merge has no duplicate values. The `merge` method works for matching across multiple columns, which isn't easily possible with `isin`.